# Not deleting my records in database

Tags: mysql

I tried to delete counter 000004 that has id 1, But everytime I delete a records all 000004 deleting in my database. What is the problem?

Purchase_Order

```
counter |  id  |

000004  |  1   |
000004  |  2   |
000007  |  3   |
000005  |  4   |
```

rfq.php

```
if(isset($_GET['de']))
{
$del_id=$_GET['de'];

$sql1 = $mysqli->query("DELETE FROM purchase_order WHERE counter ='$del_id'");

if($sql1)
{
echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.history.go(-1);</script>'; 
}
}
```

And this is the link sending id

rfq_list.php

```
<td align="center"><a href="rfq.php?de='.$row["counter"].'" onclick="return confirm(\'Really want to delete ?\');"></a></td>
```

Comment: Why do you use mysqli if you then make a gaping SQL injection exploit anyway? Also, what the HELL is a `GROUP BY` clause doing in a `DELETE` statement? I can't even fathom how that is supposed to work - you're probably getting a huge error which is hidden by the redirect.

Comment: Would you explain SQL injection in my code?

Comment: `/mysqlinjectionfile.php?de=';TRUNCATE%20TABLE%20purchase_order;select%20'`

Comment: in your where you search for counter="00004" not the id, modify it to id="$del_id" will do

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes so what should I do? Please tell me, I want to learn to how to prevent SQL Injection

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 0):

To specify multiple deletion criteria, use `AND`:

```
DELETE FROM purchase_order WHERE counter = '000004' AND id = 1;
```

Comment: How I can get id value?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

**rfq_list.php**

```
<td align="center"><a href="rfq.php?id='.$row["id"].'&&de='.$row["counter"].'" onclick="return confirm(\'Really want to delete ?\');"></a></td>
```

Here,along with the `counter value` we are passing the `value of id` in `<a href>`.

**rfq.php**

```
if(isset($_GET['de']) && isset($_GET['id']))
{
$del_id=$_GET['de'];
$id=$_GET['id'];

$sql1 = $mysqli->query("DELETE FROM purchase_order WHERE counter ='$del_id'  and id='$id'");

if($sql1)
{
echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.history.go(-1);</script>'; 
}
}
```

This will `delete` records having `counter` value `000004` AND `id` = `1`.